# Prolog, X is older than Y

Tags: prolog, predicate

I need to write a predicate that gives true if X is older than Y. MY codes are below. I don't see anything wrong yet. Please help me.

```
born(jan, date(20, 3, 1977)).

born(joris, date(17, 3, 1995)).

born(jesus, date(24, 12, 0)).

born(joop, date(30, 4, 1989)).

before(date(_, _, Year1), date(_, _, Year2)) :-
      Year1 < Year2.

before(date(_, Month1, Year ), date(_, Month2, Year)) :-
      Month1 < Month2.

before(date(Day1, Month, Year ), date(Day2, Month, Year)) :-
      Day1 > Day2.

older(X, Y) :-
      X \= Y,
      born(X, B1),
      born(Y, B2),
      before(B1, B2).
```

Query shoul give this.

```
?- older(jesus, Y).
jan,
joris,
joop.
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's the source of the problem you report but is it intentional that you have `Month1 < Month2` and `Day1 > Day2` ?  I'd have thunk those chevrons would be the same ?

Comment: No. Thank you for correcting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison `X\= Y` in `older/2` is being issued when either `X` and/or `Y` may be uninstantiated which will fail. You have to issue that comparison after you know they are instantiated with proper values, i.e. after calling `born/2` for each of them:

```
older(X, Y) :-
      born(X, B1),
      born(Y, B2),
      X \= Y,
      before(B1, B2).
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, the third clause of `before/2` should be:

```
before(date(Day1, Month, Year ), date(Day2, Month, Year)) :-
      Day1 < Day2.
```

Sample run:

```
?- older(jesus, Y).
Y = jan ;
Y = joris ;
Y = joop ;
false.
```

Comment: Yes it worked. I understand it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: If every person can only have one birthday, the `\=` is not needed at all: `before` can only succeed if the birthdays are different, and that implies that the persons are different as well.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Indeed. Provided a person only has one birthday, the comparison` X \=Y` is not required for the procedure to compute proper solutions.